keep getting error when executing raw sql in .net and mysql
I'm using EFCore 7.0 and Pomelo 7.0 with MySQL 8.0. When I execute raw SQL in NetCore project, it has error. This is a working way in previous version.
The code is:
var cnt = context.Database.SqlQuery<int>($"SELECT COUNT(*) AS CNT FROM TABLE").FirstOrDefault();

It keeps getting error

MySqlConnector.MySqlException: 'Unknown column 't.Value' in 'field
list'' ef core raw sql

Any help will be appreciated.

You have a table named Table ? I'm guessing no, but its kind of hard to think about what's wrong when you are hiding the query from us.

The documentation states:

However, since your SQL becomes a subquery whose output column needs to be referenced by the SQL EF adds, you must name the output column Value.

This applies to any scalar (single-column) raw query using Database.SqlQuery. So just add the column alias Value
var cnt = context.Database.SqlQuery<int>($@"
SELECT COUNT(*) AS Value
FROM `TABLE`;
").First();


Thank you very much! It works! Another question is that can we dynamic set the table name? like var table = "table1"; var cnt = context.Database.SqlQuery($@"
SELECT COUNT(*) AS Value
FROM {table};
").First();  It seems like set table variable in string doesn't work.

@viscroad no, the table name cannot be parameterized in SQL; there may be a way to flip this to a systables query where the name is parameterized, but the query would look completely different - something like SELECT TABLE_ROWS FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_NAME = ...

@viscroad No you can't, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/78534092/14868997
